# ng-strict-di throwing error even though no DI is used

Tags: angularjs, strict

I'm following a tutorial for AngularJS and there seems to be an issue with `ng-strict-di` which is being used. I do understand what its for, but I don' understand why it throws the error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
>   Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($provide) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

even though im not yet using any DI in the project. Also I can't find the code `function($provide)` which obviously produces this error (missing DI annotation) anywhere in my sources. Is it possible that one of the libraries included via `node_modules` creates this error? The application does run if I remove the `ng-strict-di` directive.

/Edit: It seems that the lines

```
    modules = modules || [];
modules.unshift(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.value('$rootElement', element);
}]);
```

are responsible for throwing this error. But those are in the AngularJS library itself, so I don't understand it...

Comment: Why are you editing my question?

Comment: (You can read more about editing questions in [_When should I edit posts?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) section)

Comment: Not answering my question...

Answer (score 1):

`ng-strict-di` tells angularjs to initialize the dependency injector in strict mode. That is, you have to declare the injection like this:

```
// using explicit annotations
.controller('GoodController1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
}])
```

Instead of like this:

```
// not using annotations
.controller('BadController', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
})
```

[Explicit annotations](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/docs/api/auto/service/$injector) are meant to protect your dependencies' names after minify/uglify, as the process changes the argument name preventing angularjs to identify which component to inject where. In addition, enabling `ngStrictMode` helps you to make sure all your dependencies are annotated explicitly (e.g., `['$scope', function($scope){}]`) and therefore protected from the uglification process.

> Ref.: [ngApp](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/docs/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

As it can confirmed by the snippet bellow, other modules indeed affect the `ngStrictDi` behavior, so if you are using any third party module on your app, there's a chance that one (if not many) of them is causing this.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['myModule'])
  .controller('badController1', function() { })

angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('badController2', function($scope) { })
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
  <div ng-controller="badController1"></div>
  <div ng-controller="badController2"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
```

In conclusion, if you are not uglifying your code, you can remove it from your `ngApp` element and everything will be fine. However, if you are doing this intentionally to remind you to protect dependencies' names, make sure all modules being used by your app are using explicit annotations when declaring components (usually the production builds of libraries are already notated).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought so... The weird thing is, it is a boilerplate application from Todd Motto, so I think it should run out of the box as he also explains it. There is a Gulp-Process behind it for minification/uglifiyng, but I guess for the sake of following his instructions I do need to remove it. I just don't understand why... Weird that it doesn't work for me... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Vortilion the gulp process should be using [ngAnnotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate), it basically converts normal injection to explicit annotated ones during the build process so that your dist are safely annotated.

Comment: It does, still it doesnt work... https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ultimate-angular-master-seed/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js